# Remove line breaks from XDocument XElement.Value

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Given the following XML:

```
<Samples>
    <Sample>
        <Text>
            This is example #1
        </Text>
        <Author>
            Author 1
        </Author>
    </Sample>       
    <Sample>
        <Text>This is Example #2</Text>
        <Author>Author 2</Author>
    </Sample>
</Samples>
```

And sample C# load code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, @"App_Data\Samples.xml"), LoadOptions.None);

var results = (from node in doc.Root?.Elements("Samples")
    select new Sample()
    {
        Author = node.Element("Author")?.Value,
        Text = node.Element("Text")?.Value
    }).ToList();
```

Is there a way to ignore Line Breaks in the `XElement` node values upon load? I end up with extra line breaks in the value for the first example because of how the source is formatted.

I know I could manually do the following in the `select`, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way that would handle it for all elements in the file.

`Author = node.Element("Author")?.Value.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "")`

Comment: Can you just call `Trim` of your value? It should remove all white spaces from beginning/end of your string.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Yes, that is an option.  I just wanted to make sure I am not missing something that would cause the file to be read in that way without me having to do it on each value.